# What is "onkeyup" in gamepad api?

Tags: javascript, gamepad-api

I'm experimenting a little with gamepad api. When a button is pressed, it gets "fired" all the time until the button is released. This is cool for something like running or shooting in a game, but problematic, when I want to navigate inside a menu (e.g. going 16 menu items down instead of one).

On a normal keyboard, I would use onkeyup/onkeydown to see, when a button press has ended. But on gamepad api, I didn't find something like that.

JS:

```
var gamepadPressCounter = 0;

function update() {
  const gamepads = navigator.getGamepads();
  if (gamepads[0].buttons[0].pressed === true)  {
    gamepadPressCounter++;
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

So, do you know a way to get the gamepadPressCounter only one up per press and not infinite times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check it against whether it was `pressed` last time you checked.  It doesn't fire events, it is stateful.  You are directly checking if the button is pressed or not.

Make a variable to store the state of the button last time you checked and compare it to see if it has changed from last time.

```js
const anyButtonPressedChangeListener = {
  listeners: [],
  addListener(cb) {
    this.listeners.push(cb);
  },
  signal(state) {
    for (const cb of this.listeners) {
      cb(state);
    }
  }
}

let buttonstate = false;

const loop = () => {
  const gamepads = navigator.getGamepads();
  const gamepad = gamepads[0];

  if (gamepad) {
    const statenow = gamepad.buttons.some(btn => btn.pressed);
    if (buttonstate !== statenow) {

      buttonstate = statenow;
      anyButtonPressedChangeListener.signal(statenow);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Not connected");
  }

  setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}

anyButtonPressedChangeListener.addListener((buttonState) => {
  console.log(`Any button pressed changed to ${buttonState}`);
});

loop();
```